# What is this plant with yellow flowers that keep reaching up and up and up?

Tags: identification

Can someone help me identify this plant please the shoot with pretty yellow flowers keep going up and up? It's a very nice plant that's growing in a small pot on my kitchen window sill? I've got seeds while out and forgot to mark the seeds.

[image]

Comment: I took this picture last week it has now grown twice as big and the shoot is twice as high!! and amazing plant

Comment: It looks to me like a Shanghai Bok Choi that has bolted and set flowers.

Comment: @AlMaki - post this as an answer - you're absolutely right, its pak choi (or bok choi) that has 'bolted' or flowered

Answer (score 4):

It's [Shanghai Bok Choi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bok_choy) that has flowered.